# how to out all data from database table?

Tags: php

I have this query  but the result just the last row in database table
(I want to show all rows in table:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM LESSONS WHERE L_STATE='0' ORDER BY ID DESC") or die($sql_error);
if(mysql_num_rows($sql) > 0){
    $resultset = array();
    while($rs = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){
        $resultset[] = $rs;
    }
    foreach ($resultset as $rs){
        $l_id = $rs['ID'];
        $l_title = $rs['L_TITLE'];
        $l_comments = $rs['L_COMMENTS'];
        $l_views = $rs['L_VIEWS'];
    }
}else{
        $l_id = $no_data;
        $l_title = $no_data;
        $l_comments = $no_data;
        $l_views = $no_data;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're repeatedly overwriting the same variables `$l_id`, `$l_title` and so on with the next row until the last one... and then you're surprised that you only get the last row?

You need to have your output stuff be inside the loop for it to work.

Answer (score 1):

You are looping over your result set, assigning your results to their respective variables, then doing nothing with them. Each time the loop iterates, said variables are overwritten, thus the reason you are getting only the last row.